# Remove RadSiteMap Class in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I'm working on styling the breadcrumb module.

Am I able to remove this class: `RadSiteMap`? I'd like to add my own styles to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can remove that particular class, because I believe it is automatically generated by the control as it renders (you'd have to inherit from it and override this behavior, and even then I'm not sure it's possible).

your best bet is to use CSS to override that class properties. What you can do however, is use an external template (http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/josh-morales-blog/2011/05/10/mapping_external_templates_for_sitefinity_4_widgets) which will allow you to change the default CSS styles applied to the control (for breadcrum it has a wrapper class of "sfBreadcrumbWrp" and label class of "sfBreadcrumbLabel"

These are defined right in the template and can be changed as needed.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. SF is nice but not very designer friendly as you have to override styles and can't just have a naked base.